# Do I need a service?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I`m trying to build an app, and one activity is "Radio" where I have a streaming online Radio. If i click play, everything works fine, it plays, when I click stop, it stops. But the problem is when I change the activity, ex: from "Radio" to "Home", or "Contact" and come back to "Radio", radio still runs, and if I want to stop it, doesn't work. but if I hit play, the music duplicates and therefore I have the same radio open two times. It looks like the application doesn't know that Radio already runs. Do I need a service object, or what? If I need a service can someone explain me where exactly in the code should I implement it? Here is my Java code:

```
public class radioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


int length;
Button b1;
private Button Button1;
private Button Button2;
private String STREAM_URL = "http://192.99.35.93:6370/;stream.mp3";
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonpredica1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonpredica2);



    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    mPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock = ((WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))
            .createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "mylock");

    wifiLock.acquire();
    wifiLock.release();

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
                                   public void onClick(View v) {

                                       try {
                                           mPlayer.reset();
                                           mPlayer.setDataSource(STREAM_URL);
                                           mPlayer.prepareAsync();
                                           mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {

                                                   mPlayer.start();

                                               }
                                           });
                                       } catch (IOException e) {
                                           e.printStackTrace();
                                       }
                                   }
                               });



    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       mPlayer.stop();
                                       }


    });
```

Comment: You do not need a `service` but you do need a `singleton` (and a `service` is a handy way of getting one).

Comment: Do you have an example of singleton in my case?

Answer (score 2):

Your `MediaPlayer` is being created each time you click on start button, so multiple instance of `MediaPlayer` are playing `Radio`

If you dont want your `MediaPlayer` to be running when you switch Activities you can call `mPlayer.stop();` in `onPause()` of your `Activity`

You can have a couple of options here, one would be to create a `Singleton Instance` of your MediaPlayer object so when you go to and fro from your `RadioActivity`, the same instance of the `MediaPlayer` Object is being used which will help you control the `MediaPlayer`

> Singleton design pattern in Java. Singleton Pattern says that just"define a class that has only one instance and provides a global point of access to it". In other words, a class must ensure that only single instance should be created and single object can be used by all other classes.

Comment: How Can I create a single ton instance in my case? I did some researches, but I`m a little confused.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Akayh/5566992 , these gist have a good example,

Comment: Ok, I created a new class single ton, and I copy&pasted everyhing from singleton class in the link that you sent me. Now, in my case, Activity A, would be all activities, and Activity B would be radioActivity, right?

Comment: Yes it would be and wherever you want to use `MediaPlayer` you can call `Singleton.getInstance()`

Comment: I tried that way, and now my application crashes...Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Samuel\AndroidStudioProjects\FRBCArizona\app\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRunSlicer\debug\folders\1\5\slice_1\buildId.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: can you clean and rebuild your project ?

Comment: how can I do that? sorry, I`m beginner in android studio. Just go to build and then clean and rebuild project?

Comment: yes definitely , and can you add your Singleton class in the question ?

Comment: It works now. I cleaned and built it. I still have to figure it out the thing with Singleton...

Comment: what do you mean by adding the Singleton class in the question?

Comment: means your code so that we can see if there is any issue

Comment: You dont need to add it in the answer, you can edit your question to add the codes and you will have to change the Singleton class as per your needs, the code i mentioned is just a rough idea of how you can do that :)

Comment: What do I need exactly to put in the Singleton for my needs?